# Audio does not play when first clicked, only after second click (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Add added audio to my simple website and when i first click the button the audio does not play. After the second click it will play. If I wait a while then the problem will return.

There are no errors in the console and I even see chromes speaker icon on the tab but hear nothing.

Play

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // play audio on button click
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var audio = new Audio()
        audio.src = '1.ogg'
        // listen for can play event
        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
            audio.play()
        })
    });
</script>
```

I also tried howler.js but the same problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // play audio on button click
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = '1.ogg';

         // added a volume value
        audio.volume = 1;

        // listen for can play event
        audio.addEventListener('canplay', function () {

// try a console log to see if the function is called correctly
    console.log("hello");

            audio.play();
        })
    });
</script>
```

i added a console log to see if your function is really called
and put an volume so you are sure that the volume is not 0

Answer (score 0):

Works fine

```js
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var audio = new Audio()
  audio.src = 'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3'
  audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    audio.play()
  })
});
```

```html
<button id="play">play</button>
```